# AppleID Not been accepted in XCode account pane

Tags: xcode, apple-id

I've notived my Apple ID is not been accepted within XCode when I try add an Apple ID in the XCode accounts pane of preferences.

I have tested the account details in both the member ceter and itunes connect sites and the account is fine.

When I add the account details and click 'Add' I get the message:

```
john@abcdef.com could not sign in. Please sign in with an app-specific password. You can create one at appleid.apple.com
```

Any ideas? I've updated XCode (7.2.1) and Yosemite (10.10.5), rebooted etc but same thing everytime.

Note: I have a second apple id which does NOT have a developer license, I use this for my ipad store purchases and this logs into XCode fine strangely.

John

Comment: Is the AppleID you're attempting to sign in with registered as an Apple Developer?

Comment: Yep, seems I was using my non developer apple id, really got to get organised and remove the one I dont use...Cheers Slightly. Make this an answer and I will award

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Apple ID you're using is registered as an Apple Developer, XCode does not function with normal Apple IDs since they aren't linked to Apple's developer tools.